# PHP Html Dom/Parser

Tags: php, html, dom

i) I need to extract few elements from a html page using php.

ii) Am using html dom parser.

iii) I have been able to extract all `**<a>**s, **<b>**s, **<li>**s`, etc.

iv) How should I be able to extract elements of the type/enclosed within

```
**<td class = ""><a href = "">ABC</a></td>**
```

Anything using **href**, i.e. **property of *href***

**Note:** I need to extract **ABC**

Comment: If you can extract the <a> element, then you can just get the required attribute, e.g. `$link = $aElement.getAttribute('href')`

Comment: are you referring to this library? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: @aleks G: that's what i wanted... I'll try right away...! thanx :)

Comment: This is sufficiently explained in the SimpleHtmlDocs: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Yes. the same... I am able to extract all links and using $link->href, displays the url, but not the anchor, if i mean right, i.e. within <a> and </a>...!

Comment: In simplehtmldom, it has methods like $element-> innertext or $element-> plaintext  etc. Have you looked into that ?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but, I have worked with phpquery before and found it to be a great tool to do that kind of work.

http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Comment: I'm pretty sure phpquery is unmaintained and buggy. I would use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You will not get the entire structure using the DOM Parser.

You should use `getAttribute()` method for that purpose. [Check here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php)

Here is a simple example also

```
$markup = file_get_contents($someplace);
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom -> loadHTML($markup);
$tds = $dom -> getELementsByTagName("td");
foreach($tds as $td) {
    echo $td -> getAttribute("class");
}
```